# .htaccess - Allow access only if URL matches exactly

Tags: .htaccess

I have a file (www.sample.com/sample.json).

I would like the file to be accessed only by the URL (www.sample.com/sample.json?custom-text).

If it's accessed without the custom-text, I want it to redirect to homepage or show a forbidden error.

I **do not want** to make any changes to my site www.sample.com. I want all the changes only to the file, sample.json (www.sample.com/sample.json)

I'm new to .htaccess, so sorry if the terms I used are wrong. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^custom-text$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^sample\.json$ - [F,NC]
```